# javascript input textbox link

Tags: textbox

i want to create a input textbox with value link and write a code like this:

```
<form> 
<input name="Textboxfield" type="text" value=".jpg"><br> 
<input name="Launchlink" type="button" value="Launch link" onclick="location.href=this.form.elements['Textboxfield'].value"> 
</form>
```

this is a good code for me but have some problems.
in this code the value ".jpg" is variable but i wants to keep it stable who when user insert his/her number in textbox, can go to destination link.

for example:

i insert my number 22456 in this textbox like this: 22456.jpg
and when i press botton the page directly go to my file (a pic).
but
when i insert my number without .jpg format the page goes wrong and break the system (show index page)

and thats my problem! how can i have stable value link ".JPG" who when user jus isert his/her number to textbox the page directlty go to his/her file and show it.

also you can see this image:
http://0o.8415.2.img98.com/out.php/i543815_code.jpg

please help me guys...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<form><input name="Textboxfield" type="text" value=".jpg"><br>
<input name="Launchlink" type="button" value="Launch link" onclick="location.href=this.form.elements['Textboxfield'].value + '.jpg'"> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the textbox value ends with ".jpg" using Javascript, and if it doesn't, append ".jpg" to whatever value is in the textbox. You could add this function to the onClick() handler of your button or somewhere.

You could write the function checkJPG() as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function checkJPG() {
        var myText = document.getElementByID("myTextBoxID").value;
        if (myText.substr(-1, 4) == ".jpg")
            //do nothing
        else
           //append .jpg to the value in the textbox
    }

</script>
```